# How the request.data can used for switching the django class view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to use single API to call the different class based view. Actually planning to solve this by using another function. Is this pythonic way?

My Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from masterdata import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('AAA/', views.AAAList.as_view()),
    path('AAA/<str:pk>/', views.AAADetails.as_view()),
    path('BBB/<str:pk>/', views.BBBList.as_view()),
    path('BBB/<str:pk>/', views.BBBDetails.as_view()),
    ]


urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

my Views.py

```
class AAAList(APIView):
   "some operation"

class AAADetails(APIView):
   "some operation"

class BBBList(APIView):
   "some operation"

class BBBDetails(APIView):
   "some operation"
```

My actual need is I want to switch these class using single Url with passing the body data in the method.
url looks like,

```
path("",views."somefunction or class")
```

How can I achieve this?

i try to solve this by an creating function in views.py

```
def switcher(request):
if request.GET.get("body param")==AAA:
    return AAA.as_view()(request)
elif request.GET.get("body param")==AAA:
    return BBB.as_view()(request)
```

Comment: Your use case would be useful because this is not how views a supposed to work. Depending on your use case, i would either redirect or implement the logic in the serializer

Comment: Just have multiple methods in the same view class to implement your different use cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different request methods (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT etc) in sinlge APIView.

Alternately you can pass a variable in request params to validate and call the specific function. Ideally it also depend on the approach you are using the the project size also.

For help you  can see this link.
https://testdriven.io/blog/drf-views-part-1/